# sorting a series by the powers of the variable... Sort of a generalized binomial sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I am just wondering if there is any analytical solution for the coefficients  $c_n$ in the equation below:

$$\sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{N!} (a x^p  + b x^q)^N 
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n  x^n$$

where $p$ and $q$ are positive integers, and $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

Basically, if reordering the terms and sorting by power, what would be the coefficients.

I appreciate if you could provide a reference. Thanks !

Comment: It is possible... though likely going to be extremely messy...

Answer (score 0):

The summation on the left is the series for $\exp(ax^p+bx^q) = \exp(ax^p)\exp(bx^q)$ the product of two exponentials and it is easy to get the expansion of both of these. The coefficients of a product is just the convolution of the coefficients of the factors. So we use the series expansions to get

$$  \exp(ax^p)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^kx^{pk}=:\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i,\quad \exp(bx^q)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b^kx^{qk}=:\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_jx^j $$

where $a_{pk}=a^k,\; b_{qk}=b^k$ and zero otherwise. We multiply them together to get

$$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i \sum_{j=0}^\infty b_jx^j = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\Big(\sum_{i+j=n}a_ib_j\Big)x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n.$$